# Find the sids of suppliers who supply a red part AND a green part

Tags: sql, db2

i have a question about some sql.

Thank you very much for your Help.

I have tried to Join the two tables, but i dont know how to get the output needed.

```
Select SID, COLOR from cat c1 JOIN par p ON c1.PID = p.PID;

SID  COLOR     
---  ---------

S1  red       
S1  silver    
S1  red       
S2  red       
S2  red       
S2  red       
S3  red       
S3  green     
S4  trans     
S4  cyan      
S4  magenta
```

This is the output i need:

```
SID    COLOR1       COLOR2     
-----  ----------  ---------- 
S3     green        red
```

This are the provided Tables:

```
SELECT * FROM parts 



PID    PNAME      COLOR        WEIGHT CITY       
-----  ----------  ----------  ------ ----------

P1    Nut        red            13 London     
P2    Bolt       black          18 Paris      
P3    Screw      red            17 Rome       
P4    Screw      silver         14 London     
P5    Cam        trans          12 Paris      
P6    Cog        cyan           19 London     
P7    Nut        magenta        15 -          
P8    Wheel      red            15 Munich     
P9    Bearing    green          15 Milano     

  9 record(s) selected. 




SELECT * FROM catalog 

SID   PID   COST         
-----  -----  ------------ 

S1    P3            0.50 
S1    P4            0.50 
S1    P8           11.70 
S2    P1           16.50 
S2    P3            0.55 
S2    P8            7.95 
S3    P8           12.50 
S3    P9            1.00 
S4    P5            2.20 
S4    P6      1247548.23 
S4    P7      1247548.23 

  11 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: What flavor of sql are you using?  If it is mysql, you can use [group_concat()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: I use IBM db2 express-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by cat.sid` and put the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select 
  c.sid, 
  min(p.color) color1 ,
  max(p.color) color2
from cat c inner join par p 
on c.pid = p.pid
where p.color in ('green', 'red')
group by c.sid
having count(distinct p.color) = 2
```

After selecting only parts with the 2 colors, there will be only suppliers who supply 1 or both colors.
The condition `having count(distinct p.color) = 2` returns only the suppliers who supply both colors. 
`min()` and `max()` return the 2 colors. They are not really needed in this case but I preferred to use them instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: Could you maybe explain it please

Comment: i didnt understand it complete but your answer solves my problem